# Como hospedar um site no meu próprio pc?

Tags: dns

Como hospedar no meu pc, com o meu domínio, um site que fiz em html, css e javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o site é estático (HTML + JS) há uma dezena de excelentes opções gratuitas para isso, tornando-se ainda mais desaconselhável seguir com essa ideia. Se o objetivo é meramente educacional, então pode continuar a ler a resposta.

Gerenciar um servidor, por mais simples que seja, não é uma tarefa fácil, portando não aconselho fazê-lo.

Expor uma máquina na rede pública é extremamente arriscado, portanto não aconselho fazê-lo.

Uma máquina capaz de ficar ligada 24x7 não deverá ser uma máquina normal, sendo cara e com custos associados, como gastos de luz, portanto não aconselho fazê-lo. Há alternativas, como usar um raspberry pi para isso. Dependendo do número de requests ele aguenta sem problemas.

É preciso ter um IP fixo, o que não é comumente oferecido pelas operadores residenciais de internet, portanto não aconselho fazê-lo. Há alternativas como usar um "dynamic dns", para que no lugar do IP seja usado um nome, mas as melhores opções são pagas.

Se ainda assim pensar em colocar um servidor disponível 24x7 numa rede pública, a única coisa que precisa fazer é alterar a tabela de DNS do seu domínio. A maioria dos provedores de domínios já oferece esse tipo de serviço (possuem nameservers próprios).

Para definir que "máquina" deve responder por um domínio basta alterar o "DNS" criando uma entrada do tipo `A` com o seu domínio apontando para o seu IP público. Ou uma entrada do tipo `AAAA` se o IP for v6. Ou uma entrada do tipo `CNAME` se preferir usar um outro nome (usando o "dynamic dns).

Agora, se você tem essa dúvida, aconselho que NÃO siga com isso.